# How can I get a path with fzf.vim and use to insert a snippet?

Tags: fzf

I am trying to create a macro which reproduces the behaviour of CtrlP as in this webpage: https://www.edwinwenink.xyz/posts/48-vim_fast_creating_and_linking_notes/.

However, even if fzf can easily select a file, I don't know how to get its result inside a function so as to insert a snippet (a markdown link in this case).

Any ideas ?  Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Interesting question—doesn't fzf provide "sinks" as an abstraction for "do what you want with the result"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
function! HandleFZF(file)
    echo a:file
endfunction
command! -nargs=1 HandleFZF :call HandleFZF(<f-args>)
```

Then, to invoke fzf, run:

```
call fzf#run({'sink': 'HandleFZF'})
```

Comment: Works great ! Thanks !!